# Таймер для удаления записей в БД JSP

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jsp, время

Делаю сайт на JSP. В базу данных(в отдельную таблицу) записываю юзеров при авторизации(лоиг, хеш), так же создаются куки сроком на час(временно).
И возникла потребность автоматически удалять записи в бд(в браузерах куки сами очищаются через указанное время). 
Собственно - как это можно сделать?
Погуглв понял что можно сделать ивент в самой MYSql, можно запускать на сервере отдельный потом(Thread) и делать ему *sleep* и после этого очищать записи. Всё бы ничего но есть один маленький нюанс.
Все эти методы будут удалять все записи ибо(по логике) время будет у всех не то что на данный момент (NOW()). Вот пример как это делать в MySql:

```
-- Процедура удаления старых записей
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `deleteTime`()
    COMMENT 'Удаляем старые записи'
BEGIN
      DELETE FROM MEMORY WHERE time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) LIMIT 1;
END

-- Событие срабатывающее каждый 5 минут
CREATE EVENT `deleteEvent` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
    COMMENT 'Событие вызывающее процедуру удаления старых записей'
    DO call deleteTime()
```

Таким же образом будет работать и Отдельный поток - там будет посылаться запрос и всё: `DELETE FROM MEMORY WHERE time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) LIMIT 1;`

Мне же нужно что бы записи удалялись только те которые были созданы час назад(+- пару минут). А те которые были созданы в течении этого часа оставались.

Это реально?

Comment: но там же не просто `NOW()`, а `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` - то есть на час раньше, чем `NOW()`.

Comment: @Nofate тобишь он удалит все записи которые были добавлены час назад? а те которые на протяжении этого часа не тронет?

Comment: Удалит записи, которые были добавлены более часа назад. Вы вообще пробовали запускать команды?

Comment: @Nofate ещё нет. Щас попробую.

Comment: Зачем их в базу вообще надо было помещать?

Comment: @Sergey а где мне хранить данные юзера? Как я узнаю авторизовался или нет? Куки можно подменить.

Comment: Для таймера модно использовать @Scheduler. Примеры по ссылке https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm

Answer (score 2):

Специально для поддержания сеанса связи предусмотрена `HttpSession`.
Поддерживается сервером приложения автоматически. Создаётся вызовом `Session s = request.getSession()`.
Для хранения своих данных на протяжении сессии предоставляет атрибуты. `s.setAttribute("myDataKey", myData)` `myData = s.getAttribute("myDataKey")`.

Лучше, когда это работает в связке со встроенным механизмом авторизации сервера приложений.
Практически все сервера позволяют определить `realm` (у всех свои вариации на данную тему, но тем не менее всё одинаково) аутентификации через базу данных. Надо только настроить сервер, приложение (Подкрутить пару|тройку xml)

Далее открываются разные возможности. Рассмотрим только одну.

При программной аутентификации необходимо вызвать `request.login(username, password)`. (username и password получаете через свою форму).

При успешном login создаётся сессия как уже писано выше `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` (Впрочем сессию можно создать и для не успешного login, если кому-то это надо). Сессия обычно поддерживается с помощью специального cookie, который сервер сам добавляет в запросы/ответы.

Сведения о подключившемся пользователе можно получить так
`String username = request.getRemoteUser()`
`Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal()`
Если надо всегда иметь под рукой более полную информацию о пользователе (кроме username), то обычный приём такой
Извлечь из базы нужные сведения, используя в качестве ключа username.
Поместить эти данные в атрибуты сессии `session.setAttribute("RealName", dao.findRealName(username))`

Теперь когда нужно показать где-то на страничке, получить из сессии `session.getAttribute("RealName")`

В JSP должны быть специальные объекты для доступа к атрибутам сессии `${sessionScope.RealName}`

Так же очень удобно поместить в сессию признак аутентификации. Если `login` был успешен, то `session.setAttribute("auhtenticated", true)`. Всегда можно проверить, что пользователь успешно прошёл проверку. `if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(session.getAttribute("auhtenticated"))) { \\ Велкам ... } else { \\ Пошёл на фиг ... }`

Для завершения сессии используется `session.invalidate()`.
`request.logout()` может быть вызван для об-null-ения `UserPrincipal`, `RemoteUser`.

Это конечно не всё, но и так уже много написано. Будут попадать подводные камни, но они обходятся, исключая действительно запущенные случаи.

Зачем изобретаете свои корявые велосипеды, если уже всё предусмотрено на уровне стандарта и разработчик серверов приложений подчиняются этим стандартам? (Если только не для целей изучения техники аутентификации с перспективой когда-нибудь занять место такого разработчика)

Comment: А как быть если юзер закроет вкладку ну или браузер? сессия пропадёт и все атрибуты и всё что в  ней было тоже. Как мне тогда определять авторизован ли юзер? Каждый раз вводить логин и пароль - это задолбит. Да и как мне тогда получать данные для работы из атрибутов если их нет, если они null. коим образом?

Comment: Конечно пропадёт. А не фиг было закрывать. Обычно по этому поводу переживают только пользователи. Но на это они и пользователи, чтобы косячить и ныть. На самом деле всё решаемо либо за отдельную плату, либо с хорошими знаниями внутренностей сервера приложений можно самостоятельно разработать механизм аутентификации. Стандарта тут нет и у каждого сервера реализовано по-своему. Требуется внедрение своего обработчика на низком уровне.

Comment: А может просто получится с помощью фильтра продлить жизнь стандартному cookie сессии, чтобы он не уничтожался браузером при закрытии? Хотя вряд ли конечно. Сессия на сервере живёт по умолчанию обычно 30 минут. Это настраиваемый параметр.

Comment: насколько я знаю сессии тоже можно задавать время жизни как и кукам.

Проблема даже не в том что закрыли. а в том что данные теряются и после они будут NULL и будет вываливаться ошибка....

Comment: Если до истечения таймаута сессии подключиться заново, используя тот же cookie, то сессия будет продолжена. Ничего там не пропадёт. Проблема именно в том, что при закрытии браузер уничтожает cookie сессии. И новое подключение будет без cookie, будет запрошен логин, пароль, будет открыта новая сессия.

Comment: разве браузер не сохраняет куки при закрытии? хм. как же тогда работают сайты остальные. допустим тот же Вк или же GMail...

Comment: Для каждого cookie можно определить время жизни. Есть cookie на время сессии `Срок хранения куки истекает в следующих случаях:[19]

а) В конце сеанса (например, когда браузер закрывается), если куки не являются постоянными.
б) Дата истечения была указана, и срок хранения вышел.
в) Браузер удалил куки по запросу пользователя.` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D1.83.D0.BA.D0.B8 Для сессии создаётся непостоянный cookie

Comment: Я заметил что когда захожу первый раз на страницу в куках есть такое `JSESSIONID` она автоматом создаётся.

Comment: Да. Это кук сессии. Чему-то на на этой странице необходима сессия, вот она и создаётся.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и разъяснения. буду разбираться, если что буду писать.